# Insert multiple rows into two tables at once and relate them in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a database like this:

```
create table a (
  id serial primary key,
  data integer not null
);

create table b (
  id serial primary key,
  data integer not null
);

create table link (
  a_id integer unique not null references a(id),
  b_id integer unique not null references b(id)
);

insert into a (data) values (1),(1),(1),(2),(2),(3);
```

I'd like to `link` every row in `a` to a newly created row in `b` containing the same data.

That is, I'd like to create a row in table `b` for each row in table `a`, containing the same `data`, and I want to create a row in table `link` that links the rows in table `a` to table `b` in a one-to-one manner where the data always matches.

Is there a way to do this in a single query?

Is there a way to do this without dropping the not null constraint on the `link` table?

I was hoping I could do this:

```
with bs as (
  insert into b (data)
  select data
  from a
  returning a.id as a_id, b.id as b_id
)
insert into link (a_id, b_id)
select bs
```

However, postgres doesn't allow me to return fields that weren't inserted.